# How to replace multiple instances that match one pattern, with a modified version of that instance using RegEx in Python?

Tags: python, regex

In a sentence containing multiple words, separated by spaces, I have to replace `does n't` with `doesn't`. So I'm specifically looking for a space that occurs before a character followed by a `'`

Regex should be something like this `[a-zA-z]* [a-zA-z]'[a-zA-z]` 
The resulting string should be like this `[a-zA-z]*'[a-zA-z]`

There could be multiple instances of the matching pattern. In the above example the matching pattern is `s n't`. Basically I'm looking to remove the space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of a positive lookbehind and lookahead to make sure you capture spaces which rest in between your conditions:

```
(?<=[a-zA-z]) (?=[a-zA-Z]'[a-zA-Z])
```

https://regex101.com/r/zUCbo0/1

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. Your solution definitely worked for me! Thank you.

Comment: @AneeshBhat Very good. Please feel free to use to green check-mark to mark my answer as accepted.